# HDFS space release - optimal solution

Tags: hdfs, cloudera

I would like to release some space in HDFS, so I need to find out some of the unwanted/unused HDFS blocks/files and need to delete or archive. So what would be considered as an optimal solution as of now? I am using Clouder distribution. (My cluster HDFS capacity is 900 TB and used 700 TB)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are running a licensed version of Cloudera, you can use Cloudera Navigator to see which files have not been used for a period of time and you can assign a policy to delete them.

If not, you are likely looking at writing scripts to identify the files that haven't been used and you'll have to manually delete them.

Comment: @Gault, Could you please advise me how we can find out the files not have been used, is through audit log section or any other way? Will there be any performance over load due to this?

Comment: Srini, are you using a licensed version of Cloudera or the open source version?  If licensed version, this information is readily available through pointing and clicking in the Navigator interface. See the documentation here: https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/latest/topics/cn_iu_introduce_navigator.html#cn_topic_2.  If you are using the open source version that doesn't come with Cloudera Navigator then you will have to write scripts to traverse HDFS and search based on last access time etc.

Comment: Thanks again Gault. I am new to cloudera navigator, would you able to advise in more details, if you have some free time. If you able to provide me screen shots that would be very good.

Comment: @SriniDK, it's an extremely intuitive interface. Very easy to use. Specifically how to search for files based on age or other parameters you can watch this video: [link](https://youtu.be/SNvnq_DeCWQ?t=4m35s). The link starts 4:35 into the video where he shows how to do this.

Comment: @Gault, Thanks, I video link is very informative. My next question is how do we create a policy to delete the unused files or old files. Please suggest.

Comment: @Gault, Thanks again.